# Bukkit - Referring to a custom item in an IF statement doesn't work

Tags: bukkit

Apologies for terrible use of words but I'm not into the lingo yet.

I've been creating a spell book for a simple bukkit plugin which opens into an inventory on the right click of a certain custom item that is crafted. Here is the code

```
@EventHandler
public void onBookInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e){
    if(e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR){
        if(e.getItem() == SpellBook){
            openGUI(e.getPlayer());
```

When I try to do this ingame nothing happens. I've removed if(e.getItem() == SpellBook){ and it works as well as if I change the statement to:

if(e.getMaterial() == Material.BLAZE_POWDER){

It works as well. Probably a simple error but I only started coding a couple of days ago. Thanks for any and all helpful feedback ^_^

Comment: What's your full code for that class? It would really help if you could show it to us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things that could be wrong.

**1)**  Make sure that the class that this is in `implements Listener`, and that in your `Main` class, (the one that extends `JavaPlugin`) in the `onEnable()` method, you have:

```
this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new <class that implements Listener>(), this);
```

so if the class that your code with `@EventHandler` is in is called `Handler`, then you would use:

```
this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Handler(), this);
```

**2)** Try using `.equals()` instead of `==`:

```
if(e.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR)){
    if(e.getItem().equals(SpellBook)){
```

**3)** Make sure that `SpellBook` is actually an `ItemStack`. If it is, then you may want to try doing this if it has no `ItemMeta` (display name, lore, etc.)

```
if(e.getItem().getType().equals(SpellBook.getType())){
```

Otherwise, if it does have `ItemMeta`, you could use this:

```
if(e.getItem().getType().equals(SpellBook.getType()) && e.getItem().hasItemMeta()){
  if(e.getItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(SpellBook.getItemMeta().getDisplayName(){
    if(e.getItem().getItemMeta().getLore().equals(SpellBook.getItemMeta().getLore(){
```

So, your final code should probably look something like this:

```
@EventHandler
public void onBookInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e){
  if(e.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR)){
    if(e.getItem().getType().equals(SpellBook.getType()) && e.getItem().hasItemMeta()){
      if(e.getItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(SpellBook.getItemMeta().getDisplayName()){
        if(e.getItem().getItemMeta().getLore().equals(SpellBook.getItemMeta().getLore()){
          openGUI(e.getPlayer());
        }
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If SpellBook is a type (i.e. a Java class) then that's your problem, e.getItem() returns an instance of a class. Again, if SpellBook is a type (I can't tell with the brief code you gave), then try using `e.getItem() instanceof SpellBook` instead. Sorry if I'm way off.